# Something about prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I write the Javascript code as follow:

```js
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}
function Rectangle() {
   Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
function Tmp() {
   this.a = 0;
   this.b = 0;
}
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Tmp;
var rect = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
console.log(rect)
```

then the output is:

[image]

The rect should be initialized by constructor function Tmp.my question is where is the attribution a and b of the object rect which initialized by the constructor function Tmp?

Comment: Why would you set `Rectangle.prototype.constructor` to `Tmp`? That's a very strange, and misleading, thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The rect should be initialized by constructor function Tmp

If you want that, you'd do:

```
Tmp.call(rect);
```

...after

```
var rect = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
```

```js
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}
function Rectangle() {
     Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
function Tmp() {
   this.a = 0;
   this.b = 0;
}
//Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Tmp;
var rect = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
Tmp.call(rect);
console.log(rect);
```

`Object.create` doesn't call any functions at all, it just creates the object with the given prototype. So neither `Rectangle` nor `Shape` nor `Tmp` is called by doing `var rect = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);`.

Or if you also want `Rectangle` to do its job, replace the `Object.create` call with:

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
Tmp.call(rect);
```

---

It's **very strange** to set the `constructor` property of `Rectangle.prototype` to `Tmp`, not `Rectangle`. I would strongly suggest not doing that. And there's no need to if all you want is for `Tmp` to initialize an instance. The `constructor` property of the object referenced by `SomeFunction.prototype` should be `SomeFunction`, never anything else.